# How to derive 2D equation representing minimums of constrained 3d equation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization, 3d, surfaces

I have a 3D (multivariate) function f(x,y) which can be represented as a surface with constraints.

[image: surface]

When the surface is viewed from the side (as below), such that the Y axis is not visible, there is a line A to B, which is a 2D function of x, which represents the minimum values of f(x,y) across the full range of x and y within the constraints.

[image: side view]

For this simple example it is possible to determine the equation of this 2D function through inspection of the second chart, but I am looking for a more elegant method, such as a derivation or transform, which will allow me to arrive at the 2D equation through mathematical operations rather than methods such as curve fitting. Does such a method exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the function

$$p(x) = \min_y f(x,y)$$

Assuming there are only minima and no maxima, we can simply say that

$$p(x) = f\left(x,\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y) = 0 \right)\right)$$

which evaluates to an expression that is only dependent on $x$.

Comment: Thanks. Would you be able to expand on the method with the example f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2, for which p(x) = x^2 ?

Comment: @Caustix How do you mean?

Comment: Can you show me the steps you go through in order to get from f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2, to p(x) = x^2. Is it really as simple as just setting y=0?

Comment: @Caustix yes, for $x^2+y^2$ this is really simple.

Comment: for x^2 + y^2 -4x -4y, the minimum is when y=2. Is there any way of algebraically determining that the minimum occurs when y=2 for this equation? I had to plot a chart to determine it in this case.

Comment: $\frac {\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y) = 2* y-4 \Rightarrow y = 2$